# Passing Date Expression in SSRS using fetchXML for CRMDynamics 2016

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2016

Quite new to this area so apologies if at all I sound vague. I am trying to create date parameters in SSRS for CRM Dynamics2016.
Objective: To create a drop down containing: Last Year, Last Month, Fiscal Year, Year to Date and use them to filter field: Start Date in a table called Notification and return results

What I have tried before:
Created view with period (this will be like the field label), Begin Date and End Date but I soon realised that CRMDynamics online don't like sql anymore and that they are now more in line with fetchXML

My question is: Is there a way to pass the above mentioned date parameters in SSRS other than what I tried before?

Thanks a ton in advance for all your help!!
Cheers
Salman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you are trying to achieve is to dynamically calculate the date range parameters as all of your filter conditions can be broken down to date ranges.

- Create a regular SSRS drop down parameter (Name - "DateRange") with all the possible filter conditions LastYear, LastMonth, FiscalYear, YearToDate with the same label and values
- Add additional parameters StartDateOnOrAfter and StartDateOnOrBefore, for each specify the "Default Values" as "Specify Values" and use the expression to calculate your parameters, for example:

  ```
    For parameter - FiscalYear - StartDateOnOrAfter - 01/01/currentyear, StartDateOnOrBefore - 12/31/currentyear
    For parameter - LastMonth - StartDateOnOrAfter - Compute 1 day last month, StartDateOnOrBefore - Compute last day last month
  ```

  ... so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks mate. that should do the trick. the new fetch xml is quite limiting when compared to how we deploy SSRS reports in CRM on premise.